# Can I use same virtual environment on different computers

Tags: python, virtualenv

On my office computer, I've made `virtualenv one-for-rule-them-all` at the Dropbox folder. I want to use this environment both at work and at home. Is this possible? (currently I'm not successful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into using the `relocatable` option of virtualenv. For full documentation, see the [virtualenv documentation on the subject](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable).

One note of interest:

> Also, this does not make your packages cross-platform. You can move the directory around, but it can only be used on other similar computers. Some known environmental differences that can cause incompatibilities: a different version of Python, when one platform uses UCS2 for its internal unicode representation and another uses UCS4 (a compile-time option), obvious platform changes like Windows vs. Linux, or Intel vs. ARM, and if you have libraries that bind to C libraries on the system, if those C libraries are located somewhere different (either different versions, or a different filesystem layout).

As an alternative to this approach, I would simply manage your project/setup dependencies with setup.py requirements (`install_requires`, `setup_requires`), or pip requirements.txt file. This is much more portable and cross-platform.

Comment: Could you expend on the second part, or point to a write-up? Thanks!